# Add a SPI filter between driver controller and userspace spidev driver on Linux

Tags: linux, spi, atmel

We have Linux on a product. The customer is free to write its own application and need to use the spidev driver to access a specific peripheral.

This peripheral is accessed through the SPI master driver for Atmel processor (spi-atmel.c).

Now, I would like to control/limit some data and command which can be sent from the userspace (user application) to this particular peripheral.

I need to keep compatibility on user side and then keep the spidev interface so my basic idea would be to add a driver between the spidev and the master SPI controller but I'm not sure if it's the best way and if so how to achieve that correctly, do you have an idea ?

Thank for your help,
Regards